# Trying to us an IList.Contains with lambda, but not delegate type

Tags: linq, lambda, ilist

I'm trying to search a list and see if an ID is in it.

```
            string idText = item["FCSID"].Text;
            var sfhOptions = PathologySFHByRole.GetSFHOptionsByRoles(Model.pathologyFishCultureStation);
            if (!sfhOptions.Contains(x => x.ID == int.Parse(idText))) 
                e.Item.Cells[0].Visible = false;
```

The GetSFHOptionsByRoles returns an IList. My lambda expression gets the error:
Cannot convert the lambda expression to type SFHType because it is not a delegate type

What's the best practice for this?

Comment: Try [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any(v=vs.110).aspx) instead: `!sfhOptions.Any(x => x.ID == int.Parse(idText))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Any`:

```
int id = int.Parse(idText);
e.Item.Cells[0].Visible = sfhOptions.Any(x => x.ID == id);
```

[`IList<T>.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) expects an object of type `SFHType` instead of a  predicate.

Comment: Maybe, while you're at it, you want to convert `idText` to a number first. I'm not sure it will get parsed every time the delegate is called, but I can imagine it will.